# Visual Studio Code debugger doesn't work properly

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jestjs, vscode-debugger, ts-jest

The debugger launches, but it just doesn't go into debugger mode. Please see screen shot as below:

[image]

[image]

It just stuck at the initial launch. I can't go to next step.

It seems like jest is breaking when the debugger boots up and jest triggers all the tests to run, seems like that breaks the run of the debugger

We coded in Typescript.

Comment: How do you know it didn't finish running already?  Sometimes the debug points are not enabled automatically, allowing the program to run through the debug points without stopping.

Comment: If it finished running, it would show the testing results, line coverage, etc. But here, it doesn't show anything.

Comment: How did you launch the debugger? Did you setup your .vscode/launch.json config properly?

Comment: I think my config is fine. I directly click debug above the test case that I need to run. It was working two weeks ago. But it behaved like this since last week.